# How I can change the input color of Material UI TextField when is input is disabled [MUI v: 5.0.8]

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the border color and text color when input  is disabled. I tried all variants like you see below:

```
const textFieldStyle = {
    '& label': {
        color: darkMode?'#1976d2':'',
    },

    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        color:darkMode?'#1976d2':'',
        '& fieldset': {
          borderColor:darkMode?'#1976d2':'',
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
            borderColor: darkMode?'#1976d2':'',
        }, 
 
    },
    "& input.Mui-disabled": {
        color: "green"
      }

};
```

`<TextField value={formState.vinInput} type="text" label="Stack" sx={textFieldStyle}/>`

Rest of the style work just fine like general color and focused color!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code in v4:

```
 MuiInputBase: {
    root: {
      "&$disabled": {
        color: "red",
        border: "1px solid red"
      }
    }
  }
```

based on [Material-ui](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-themes-styleoverrides-to-emotion) documentation in version 5 The **$** syntax used with JSS will not work with Emotion. You need to replace those selectors with a valid class selector.

this is the style

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
    customDisable: {
      "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
        color: "red !important",
        "-webkit-text-fill-color": "red !important",
        borderColor: "red !important"
      },
      "& .Mui-disabled .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: "red !important"
      }
    }
  });
```

and then in TextField like this

```
<TextField
        disabled
        className={classes.customDisable}
        id="outlined-disabled"
        defaultValue="Hello World"
      />
```

here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-phoebe-cm9e7)

Comment: It's not working, idk why! All style aplied to normal input work but when I want to pply to something disabled it's not working. Btw, Mui version is 5.0.6

Comment: maybe this helps https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-phoebe-cm9e7